# Curious `dnf check-update` result with Fedora Modular repo

Tags: fedora, dnf

I noticed a curiosity on Fedora 29.  When I only enable the repo `updates-modular`, it says I have an update available for `libgit2`.  When I enable both `fedora-modular` and `updates-modular`, it does not.

I am surprised by this difference.  Is anyone able to explain it?

`dnf` does not mention any packages being held back for dependency reasons, in either case.  And adding `--best` does not make a difference to any of the commands.

```
$ sudo dnf check-update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:14 ago on Tue 08 Jan 2019 17:12:03 GMT.
$ sudo dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=fedora-modular --enablerepo=updates-modular check-update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:37 ago on Tue 08 Jan 2019 17:11:51 GMT.
$ sudo dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=updates-modular check-update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:15 ago on Tue 08 Jan 2019 17:11:51 GMT.

libgit2.x86_64                                              0.27.7-1.module_2334+e7fbee10                                              updates-modular
```

---

I am also a bit curious what that `libgit2` package is for, given that I already have `libgit2-0.27.7` from the non-modular `updates` repo.  But I don't really know anything about how to use the Fedora Modular repo :-).

```
$ sudo dnf info libgit2
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:14 ago on Tue 08 Jan 2019 17:12:03 GMT.
Installed Packages
Name         : libgit2
Version      : 0.27.7
Release      : 1.fc29
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 1.0 M
Source       : libgit2-0.27.7-1.fc29.src.rpm
Repo         : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : C implementation of the Git core methods as a library with a solid API
URL          : https://libgit2.org
License      : GPLv2 with exceptions
Description  : libgit2 is a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods
             : provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, allowing
             : you to write native speed custom Git applications in any language
             : with bindings.
```